# Show/hide images using input radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Explanation

I'm trying to show an image (and hide the others) based in an input radio selection. It does work when without `label` (also, of course, without its attributes), but when adding `label` it won't, probably because `eq($(this).index())` isn't the same as before, so it selects a different object. Both the codes are below.

### Codes

**with `label`**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#radioDiv .inputRadio').change(function() {
    $('.image').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radioDiv">
  <input id="colorRed" class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" />
  <label for="color-1" style="color: red">Red</label>
  <input id="colorYellow" class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" />
  <label for="colorYellow" style="color: yellow">Yellow</label>
  <input id="colorGreen" class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" />
  <label for="colorGreen" style="color: green">Green</label>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="image hidden red">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>

  <div class="image hidden yellow">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>

  <div class="image hidden green">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

**without `label`**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#radioDiv .inputRadio').change(function() {
    $('.image').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radioDiv">
  <input id="colorRed" class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" /> Red
  <input id="colorYellow" class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" /> Yellow
  <input id="colorGreen" class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" /> Green
</div>

<div>
  <div class="image hidden red">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>

  <div class="image hidden yellow">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>

  <div class="image hidden green">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be adding `data-*` attributes to the input radios to save they target image. In the next example I used the `data-target` attribute for hold the target image of each input radio:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#radioDiv .inputRadio').change(function()
    {
        $('.image').hide();
        $($(this).data("target")).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="radioDiv">
  <input id="colorRed" class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" data-target=".red"/>
  <label for="color-1" style="color: red">Red</label>
  <input id="colorYellow" class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" data-target=".yellow"/>
  <label for="colorYellow" style="color: yellow">Yellow</label>
  <input id="colorGreen" class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" data-target=".green"/>
  <label for="colorGreen" style="color: green">Green</label>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="image hidden red">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>

  <div class="image hidden yellow">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>

  <div class="image hidden green">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the `label` around the `input` of which the outcome would be the same without altering the indexes.

You'll want to slightly tweak the JS too so it's using the index of the `label` and not the `input`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#radioDiv .inputRadio').change(function() {
    $('.image').hide().eq($(this).parent().index()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radioDiv">
  <label style="color: red"><input class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" /> Red</label>
  <label style="color: yellow"><input class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" /> Yellow</label>
  <label style="color: green"><input class="inputRadio" type="radio" name="typeof" /> Green</label>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="image hidden red">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>

  <div class="image hidden yellow">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>

  <div class="image hidden green">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's great!! I'm accepting [Shidersz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10366495/shidersz)'s answer because it worked better for my need, but I'm also upvoting yours.